# Share string between applications on the same device

Tags: android

Is there a trusted/simple way to share string between 2 applications in the same device, NOT by intent or ContentProvider, and without the need to update manifest.xml file.

I want to use a shared/common code that share string between 2 applications on the same device
Thanks !

Comment: You denied the obvious answers... what left? Maybe TCP socket on 127.0.0.1?